# Hide select options based on multiple selects

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 select objects.

**University**

```
<select id="universitySelect" size="8" multiple>
    <option value="1" >Oxford</option>
    <option value="2" >Berkley</option>
    <option value="3" >MIT</option>
</select>
```

**Major**

```
<select id="majorSelect" size="8" multiple>
    <option value="m1" uni="1">Engineering</option>
    <option value="m2" uni="2">Business</option>
    <option value="m3" uni="1">Drama</option>
    <option value="m4" uni="3">Physical Education</option>
    <option value="m5" uni="2">Accounting</option>
</select>
```

**Students**

```
<select id="studentSelect" size="8" multiple>
    <option value="s1" uni="1" major="m1">John Doe</option>
    <option value="s2" uni="2" major="m2">Josh Smith</option>
    <option value="s3" uni="1" major="m4">Mark Demagliyeh</option>
    <option value="s4" uni="3" major="m2">Ron Teaser</option>
    <option value="s5" uni="2" major="m3">Paula Barry</option>
</select>
```

If a university is selected, I want the Major select to only show the majors in this university and the students in this university.

If Major is selected, I want to only show the students in this major, regardless of the university tag.
I don't want to remove the elements, because they might be re-selected. I just want to 'hide' them.

At the moment I am loading all the data in javascript. 3 Arrays and going over them to populate the 2nd and 3rd select based on what is selected without using the tags.

Is their any way to "hide" the elements and not have to load the arrays in javascript?

I started with this:

```
$("#universitySelect").on('change',function() {
    $("#universitySelect option:selected" ).each(function() {
            $("#majorSelect").find("uni:contains(" + $(this).val() + ")").hide();
    });
});
```

It is not working. I used contains to test first, but finally I want to use "does not contain". I am new to all jquery stuff... So I appreciate help.

Comment: use data attribute : http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp

Answer (score 1):

- As mentionned in comments, you should use data-* attribute, e.g. :

  `<option data-uni="1">foo</option>`
- `$("#majorSelect").find("uni:contains(" + $(this).val() + ")").hide();`

this line won't work, it means find elements with tag "uni" (which does not exists) int the element with id "majorSelect"

```js
$("#universitySelect").on('change',function() {
  $("#majorSelect option").hide();
  var uni = $(this).val();
  for (var i = 0; i < uni.length; i++) {
    $("#majorSelect option[uni='"+uni[i]+"']").show();
  }
});

$("#majorSelect").on('change',function() {
  $("#studentSelect option").hide();
  var major = $(this).val();
  for (var i = 0; i < major.length; i++) {
    $("#studentSelect option[major='"+major[i]+"']").show();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="universitySelect" size="8" multiple>
    <option value="1" >Oxford</option>
    <option value="2" >Berkley</option>
    <option value="3" >MIT</option>
</select>
<select id="majorSelect" size="8" multiple>
    <option value="m1" uni="1">Engineering</option>
    <option value="m2" uni="2">Business</option>
    <option value="m3" uni="1">Drama</option>
    <option value="m4" uni="3">Physical Education</option>
    <option value="m5" uni="2">Accounting</option>
</select>
<select id="studentSelect" size="8" multiple>
    <option value="s1" uni="1" major="m1">John Doe</option>
    <option value="s2" uni="2" major="m2">Josh Smith</option>
    <option value="s3" uni="1" major="m4">Mark Demagliyeh</option>
    <option value="s4" uni="3" major="m2">Ron Teaser</option>
    <option value="s5" uni="2" major="m3">Paula Barry</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("#universitySelect").on('change',function() {
        $("#majorSelect,#studentSelect").hide();
        $("#universitySelect option:selected" ).each(function() {

                $("#majorSelect,#studentSelect").find('option[uni="'+ $(this).val() +'"]').show();
        });
});

$("#majorSelect").on('change',function() {
        $("#studentSelect").hide();
        $("#universitySelect option:selected" ).each(function() {

                $("#studentSelect").find('option[major="'+ $(this).val() +' "]').show();
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i don't have the answer but when you wanna test these things you can usually write a hard-coded value instead of `$(this).val()` just to make sure there isn't a problem with referring to "this" or other such references.

so like `find("uni:contains(1)")`.

just so you can analyze what is actually not working.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this, work with multiple select :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#universitySelect').on('change',function(){
        $('#majorSelect option').hide();

        var uni = $(this).val();
        $.each(uni,function(index,value){
            $('#majorSelect').find("[data-uni='" + value + "']").show();
        });

    });

    $('#majorSelect').on('change',function(){
        $('#studentSelect option').hide();

        var major = $(this).val();
        $.each(major,function(index,value){
            $('#studentSelect').find("[data-major='" + value + "']").show();
        });

    });
});


</script>
<select id="universitySelect" size="8" multiple>
    <option value="1" >Oxford</option>
    <option value="2" >Berkley</option>
    <option value="3" >MIT</option>
</select>
Major

<select id="majorSelect" size="8" multiple>
    <option value="m1" data-uni="1">Engineering</option>
    <option value="m2" data-uni="2">Business</option>
    <option value="m3" data-uni="1">Drama</option>
    <option value="m4" data-uni="3">Physical Education</option>
    <option value="m5" data-uni="2">Accounting</option>
</select>
Students

<select id="studentSelect" size="8" multiple>
    <option value="s1" data-uni="1" data-major="m1">John Doe</option>
    <option value="s2" data-uni="2" data-major="m2">Josh Smith</option>
    <option value="s3" data-uni="1" data-major="m4">Mark Demagliyeh</option>
    <option value="s4" data-uni="3" data-major="m2">Ron Teaser</option>
    <option value="s5" data-uni="2" data-major="m3">Paula Barry</option>
</select>
```